# ironSource - How to activate a banner ad unit in an existing application

Tags: ironsource

I created an application in ironSource and activated the ad units "Rewarded Video" and "Interstitial".

[ironSource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0vsm.png)

Now I want to activate the "Banner" ad unit for this existing application, but cannot find how.

Answer (score 0):

- Login to Ironsource
- Goto Monetize -> Ad Units & Placement
- On the Right hand side goto extreme right and you will find Banner
- Inside banner create New Placement

[image]

Comment: The question was how to activate the "banner ad unit", see the [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/64a87a8f42e8b1731e07d48e71eedf86.png), and not "How to add a new banner placement."